# MVC5 WebApi 2 create not getting value from body ([FromBody])

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I created a simple create Web API 2 action that will get an object from the post body and then will set it to the DAL layer. However no matter what I do using postman to get the object into the method, it always stays null.

The model looks like this:

```
namespace WebApi.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Classes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public int MaxStudents { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateClass([FromBody] Classes classObj)
{
    if (classObj == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("missing parameters.");
    }

    var newClass = new Classes()
    {
        ClassName = classObj.ClassName,
        MaxStudents = classObj.MaxStudents
    };

    _context.Classes.Add(newClass);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    var newClassUrl = Url.Content("~/") + "/api/classes/";

    return Created(newClassUrl, newClass);
}
```

Now when I use postman I tried two options.

option 1:

```
URL: http://localhost:53308/api/classes/
Headers: Content-Type: applications/json

[
  "classObj":  {
       ClassName = "test"
       MaxStudents = 100
  }
]
```

option 2:

```
URL: http://localhost:53308/api/classes/
Headers: Content-Type: applications/json

       ClassName = "test"
       MaxStudents = 100
```

but in both cases `classObj` stays empty and it returns "missing parameters.". So obviously I'am missing something here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your payloads do not match the expectation of the action.

For example

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateClass([FromBody] Classes classObj) {
    //...
}
```

Would expect JSON data that looks like this

```
{
    "ClassName": "test"
    "MaxStudents": 100
}
```

Also given that the model posted into the action is the same type added to the store there isn't really a need to create a new instance.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateClass([FromBody] Classes classObj) {
    if (classObj == null) {
        return BadRequest("missing parameters.");
    }

    _context.Classes.Add(classObj);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    var newClassUrl = Url.Content("~/") + "/api/classes/" + classObj.Id.ToSTring();

    return Created(newClassUrl, classObj);
}
```

Comment: that worked, I guess I was thinking of too much complexity using the full object. I do have another question regarding the DTO though. I will use it to return it to the consumer, wouldn't it be better to use the Dto instead of the raw class then (although the dto here is the same as the actual model, this will not always be the case)? thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @RodneyWormsbecher, Using a DTO is how it should be done. In your example you were not using a DTO hence my suggestion about not recreating the same object.